# Threading exception when attempting to return String from async method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I am working on a Winforms app that makes some HTTP based API calls to various web services within a Timer control loop. The web services are called using the `async` keyword. The problem is that I get a Threading exception when attempting to return the result as a string.

```
private async Task<String> UpdateViaApi(ClientInfoObject clientInfoObject)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await myHttpClient.SendAsync(request);
    string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return result;
}
```

Here is how I call the method ...

```
string result = UpdateViaApi(clientInfoObject);
```

The `ClientInfoObject` is a simple class that contains data as a series of properties. Am I using Task properly?

Comment: That won't even compile. UpdateViaApi returns a `Task<string>` not a string.

Comment: I see your point. However, it does compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `await` the returned task:

```
string result = await UpdateViaApi(clientInfoObject);
```

Also, note that the method name should end in `Async`, to [conform to the convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx):

```
string result = await UpdateViaApiAsync(clientInfoObject);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I add the keyword `await` I get the error `The await operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.` Also, reading your book at the moment. Good information.

Comment: @webworm Now did you read the error message and follow the instructions that it gave you?

Comment: Indeed I did. Looks like the method that contained `UpdateViaApiAsync(clientInfoObject)` also need to be prefixed with the `await` operator.